# A relation between Hochschild cohomology of a $C^*$ algebra and its bidual

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, cohomology, c-star-algebras, noncommutative-geometry, hochschild-cohomology

Let $A$ be a $C^*$ algebra and $A''$ be its bidual with the Arens product.
Is there any relation between the Hochschild cohomolgy of $A$ with complex coefficients and the Hochschild cohomology of $A''$?

Comment: Because $A^{**}$ is a von Neumann algebra, it has no outer derivations, so its first Hochschild cohomology must be $0$. This is stated in a paper of Kadison and Ringrose here https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.acta/1485889690 with reference to citations 9, 10, and 13.